# Why are payment gateways like Paytm and Razorpay not accepting new merchants?

Tags: android, payment-gateway, payment

I have created an ecommerce app in which I want to integrate a payment gateway but none of the payment gateways are registering new users. Can you please tell me the reason ?

I tried to integrate payment gateway but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

Razorpay received a notification to submit a system audit report to the regulator. Once the RBI is satisfied with the findings, Razorpay can then start onboarding newer merchants. It's been like that since Dec 2022. There has been no update on this since then.

Reference: https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/tech/startups/rbi-asks-razorpay-stripe-to-stop-onboarding-new-merchants/articleshow/96279740.cms

Comment: Then how can I register on payment gateway as I need it in my android app. Is there any way or which company is allowed to register new user ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @gaurisrivastava, you can still submit the registration to Razorpay, their team will process your request and kyc and will notify or activate your account once they get confirmation from RBI.